# Check if value exist on duplicate rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Iam creating a query to find out the unique row from the duplicate values in mysql. But I got stuck while checking if there is some another column value exist in duplicate column values.
For example i have a table users:

```
id name gender
1  Jack Male
2  Jack Male
3  Jack Null
```

Now to find out any unique value I did use of group by like this:-

```
 SELECT name FROM users GROUP BY name;
```

So, now let say I have to check if any one these duplicate rows have a gender Male but must not have null value then it must return zero rows beacuse there is one row with null.

Suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I sounds like you want a `having` clause:

```
SELECT name
FROM users
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM( gender = 'Male' ) > 0 AND  -- has "male"
       SUM( gender IS NULL) = 0        -- gender is never `NULL`
```